# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when i run maven tests

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

Hi I am having a spring boot project and using maven. however when i run a test i am getting the error below

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:367)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:73)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.flush(PrettyPrintWriter.java:346)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1283)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1268)
    at org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:53)
    at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:33)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:40)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule$1.evaluate(WireMockRule.java:73)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
```

please find the pom.xml configurations. I am using maven sure fire plugin version 2.18.1

2.18.1

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                 <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                 <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

any idea how can i fix the issue
thank you

Comment: I also tried to run with 2.19.1 maven sure fire plugin but same results

Comment: You need to increase the memory...upgrading surefire plugin will not help...

Comment: Does this happen also for a minimal test? Probably you have a test that allocates abnormally much memory?

Comment: could you explain me what is minimal test ? thank you

Comment: Just `public class MinimalTest {
    @Test
    public void itWorks() {

    }
}`  and no other tests. Does this work?

Comment: ok so i have many tests . most of the tests works and a few of them dont work. i think once i added some powermock libraries i started to get in to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
```

by something like

```
<argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
```

to give more memory to the tests.

Comment: it didnt work  <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                     <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                     <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                   <!-- <forkCount>1</forkCount> --> 
                                       <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
               <!-- <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile> -->
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>

Comment: What do you mean by "it didnt work" ? If you still run out of Memory, increase the number.

Comment: i got the out of memory again

Comment: Two approaches: Either try some larger number or try find out if one of the tests wastes a lot of memory.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: nope i know 3 tests that cause this problem. i tried to increase the memory by setting <argLine>-Xmx4096m</argLine> it is still not working

Comment: Maybe your tests are inefficient and reserve more memory than necessary?

Comment: test is efficient . i was trying to use powermock . so i have to add some xstream jar file (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/powermockrule) powermock-classloading-xstream. this is causing high memory . have to figure out how to properly increase it